# Pin assignments do not appear to be assigning in bdf - Quartus 17.1

Tags: pins, pinout, troubleshooting, quartus

Following the pin assignment diagram in the device manual for my Max 10 DE10-Lite, I assigned all the correct pins to their associated inputs and outputs as seen below:

[image: pin assignments]

However, when I go back to my bdf file and run the full compile, the pin assignments do not appear, as they have in the past.

[image: bdf file]

I thought to myself, maybe they just aren't showing up, but they are actually still assigned. So I programmed my board, and it simply remains black, with my circuit not working at all. Has anyone seen this before? I have tried creating a new project, and still nothing.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm no Quartus expert, but a hint: Under the GUI, there is likely to be a command line interface, with ways of showing (console, or log files) how the actual compilation commands operate, and what their arguments (constraint file names etc) are. Looking at those files, you may be able to trace the pin assignments and see where they go missing.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, if you check the .QSF file in the project files, that'll be a plaintext file with all of the configurations as commands like you said.